# Looping through databases with names stored in a main database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

So I have a main database where names of other databases are stored. I need to loop trough tables of all of the databases that are stored in the main database, in some sort of join. I need an array of all rows in the station's databases that has `status != 2` using PHP and MySQLi.

The main one looks like this:

```
main.stations

+----+-----------------+------+
| ID |  station name   |  db  |
+----+-----------------+------+
|  1 | Name of station | db_1 |
|  2 | Name again      | db_2 |
|  3 | Name            | db_3 |
+----+-----------------+------+
```

All three stations have an assigned database with the name that is stated in the column `main.stations.db`

The station's database has two tables I need to loop trough and get all rows where `status != 2`. The two tables look like this (example for db_1):

```
db_1.salesReport

+----+----------+--------+
| ID |   name   | status |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 | Report 1 |      1 |
|  2 | Report 2 |      0 |
|  3 | Report 3 |      2 |
+----+----------+--------+

db_1.fuelReport

+----+----------+--------+
| ID |   name   | status |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 | Report 1 |      1 |
|  2 | Report 2 |      0 |
|  3 | Report 3 |      2 |
+----+----------+--------+
```

My question being; Is there a way to loop through databases based on database names from another database? (Of course asuming that the user has access rights to all databases)
I don't wanna add another layer in my array based on stations. I want every row from the sub-database to be a top-element, including all info from stations, in my array.

**Edit**
The output has to look something like this

```
0:{
stationID: 1
station name: Name of stations,
fromDb: salesReport //this doesn't have to be dynamically stated
name: Report 1,
status: 1
},
1:{
stationID: 1
station name: Name of stations,
fromDb: fuelReport
name: Report 1,
status: 1
},
2:{
stationID: 1
station name: Name of stations,
fromDb: salesReport
name: Report 2,
status: 0
},
3:{
stationID: 2
station name: Name again,
fromDb: salesReport
name: Report 2,
status: 0
},
```

And so on..

Comment: Show us your expected output

Comment: in MySql you can Join and Union across multiple Databases ... just saying.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Yes I know, but I don't know how to do that without knowing the database names on forehand.

Comment: Query them from the one DB, then you know them.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Yes! I for sure could split my problems into multiple while loops. I'm only asking to make my code more effective.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Edited!

Comment: You will pull from your `main` database to get the database names that you need. From that you will craft a single UNION query `SELECT * FROM db_1.SalesReport WHERE status <> 2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM db_1.FuelReport WHERE status <> 2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM db_2.SalesReport WHERE status <> 2 UNION ALL SELECT....` and execute that once. That's two trips to the database and only one while loop to loop through your `main` query to build the second query.

Comment: _Ick ..._ do you _have_ to do this?  Well, I'd probably start by looping through the main database, stashing all of the results in an array so that you could then loop through this array while establishing database-connections one at a time.